# How to import row from Excel file as list in Python?

Tags: python, excel, list

I have a row of data in an Excel document file (say column `P` until column `AD` in row `370` in `sheet1`).

How do I import this specific row as a list in Python? I need it as a list to run a cubic spline interpolation and to get the interpolated values.

Answer (score 0):

Do you have Pandas installed? 
The [read_excel](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.read_excel.html) function is what you are looking for. This basically solves your problem.

```
import pandas
pandas.read_excel(
  'path_to_file.xlsx',
  usecols="P:AD",
  skiprows=369,
  nrows=1,
)
```

However you need to have the pandas package installed with the xlrd optional dependency. So if you have pip:

```
pip install pandas
pip install xlrd
```

Let me know if it works for you.

Comment: I get ValueError: ':' is not in list... I have used r"path\excelsheet.xlsm" within pandas.read_excel(

Answer (score 0):

Try this.

```
import openpyxl 

# Give the location of the file 
path = "C:\\Users\\Admin\\Desktop\\demo.xlsx"
wb_obj = openpyxl.load_workbook(path) 
sheet_obj = wb_obj.active
row_as_list = sheet_obj.rows[370] # required row as a list
```

Answer (score 0):

first install pandas library by typing the following command in the command prompt

```
pip install pandas
```

later try this code

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.read_excel('Book1.xlsx',sheet_name='Sheet1')
a = list(df.iloc[368][15:])
```